# Spritz speed reading with Text-to-Speech (TTS)?

Tags: windows, android, speech-synthesis, reading, audiobook

I love [Spritz speed reading technology](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/speed-reading-software-for-windows).

I also love listening to text via text-to-speech technology (TTS).

I'm looking for an app (on Windows or Android) that combines both technologies. That is, as the words are Spritz-ed, they're simultaneously -- in sync -- read aloud by the app.

Also, if there is no such app, and you need incentives to develop one -- I'll HAPPILY PAY for such an app.

Edit: I'm currently using 2 ways to do something close:

1. Use Balabolka to export text to audio with a separate .SRT subtitles file. Then do one of either a. or b. to get a video file from the audio file. Then play the video file and .SRT subtitles file together in VLC.

   a. convert the audio to video by adding an image layer (I use ShotCut).

   b. use 'My MP4 GUI' to mux the audio file with a video file that doesn't have an audio layer.
2. Use Balabolka to export text to audio (MP3) with lyrics embedded as ID3v2 (File>ID3 Tags). You can read the contents of this "synchronized lyrics tag" (SYLT) in the MP3 tag manager: kid3. Next play this MP3 in Winamp with the [SYLT Lyrics plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20120311231251/https://www.compuphase.com/mp3/SYLT_index.html) installed.

Comment: Question is: how much would you pay? ;-) What's your input (plain TXT)? Which language(s) do you need? It might not be possible in real-time, since long words need to be read faster than short words. Finding the right tempo might require brute-forcing.

Comment: How fast do you need it to become? Are 500 WPM enough?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Don't need it to be too fast. 300 WPM will be enough. I'll pay $25 for it easily.